# Trouble getting CSS to align an area to the right

Tags: css, alignment

Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/gFTeG/

I'm having trouble discovering the necessary CSS to have this align to the right (I can do `text-align:right;` for the text inside of the container, but the container stays aligned to the left side of the action button).

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `right: 0;` on the `.ILdropdown .ILdropdown_content` class of your css, and you'll have it align to the right:

```
.ILdropdown .ILdropdown_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    padding: 0px;
    background: white;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
}
```

[**Check this DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/gFTeG/6/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: This floats the entire thing right.  I only want the dropdown container to be aligned to the right of the "action" box.

Comment: haha still not quite there.  I want the right edge of the content to align with the right edge of action.  Maybe I should have floated the action box to the right, then it would have made more sense =).  So, action is floated right, and the content is also floated right, but lands under it.

Comment: Man, I don't get it.  It works correectly in jsfiddle but not on my site and I have NO idea why.  For some reason when I do right:0; the content box becomes the same size as the "Actions" button.  So the text just overlaps like crazy.

Comment: @Shackrock try recreating all the `<div>`'s you have in your site in a fiddle, maybe its a position problem and the container is getting the `width` of its parent

Comment: YES!  You are a genius.  Look at this part:`#bodytopPan .ILdropdown  ul{
        left: 0;
        margin: 4px 0;` - it wasn't being used because I didn't include all the DIVs in fiddle.  DUH.  It has `left:0;` defined there, so it was blocking off both sides to the left and right.  THANK YOU!
    }

Comment: @Shackrock You're welcome sir, glad we could fix it! Good luck with your site!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misunderstood.

Add `right: 0;` to your dropdown, so it aligns to the right side of the action button.

Comment: Can you try it in jsfiddle, because I don't see how that works... haha.

Comment: Hmmm, see comment on the other answer above.

Comment: It's on private server =(, sorry.  I guess I might be on my own, ha.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the dropdown menu to appear to the right of the button. As you have your `.ILdropdown .ILdropdown_content` with `position: absolute`, you could add the `position: absolute` to the parent class and add/change `left: 100%` and `top: 0%` to the content class as shown below.

```
.ILdropdown .ILdropdown_button img {
    ...
    position: absolute;            
}
```

and

```
.ILdropdown .ILdropdown_content {
    ...
    top: 0%;
    left: 100%;
}
```

That should give the right aligned effect, shown in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gFTeG/8/). You may need to add a `position: relative` to a parent class if you want them to align horizontally. If I did misunderstand you on the position of the drop down, simply adjusting the `top` and `left` or `right` attributes will position it wherever you want.

This article from A List Apart might help with the layers of `position` attributes. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/